# Purpose of redirect_uri parameter when exchanging code for access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, rfc6749

The RFC for Oauth2 says the `redirect_uri` which was specified when generating the authorization code must be included **in the request to exchanging the code for an access token**.

From the RFC:

> 4.1.3.  Access Token Request

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by sending the
> following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
> request entity-body:

> [...]

> redirect_uri

> REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the
> authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and their
> values MUST be identical.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3

Why is the `redirect_uri` required when exchanging the code for an access token? What benefit does this provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described in
*10.6.  Authorization Code Redirection URI Manipulation:*

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6

**10.6.  Authorization Code Redirection URI Manipulation**

When requesting authorization using the authorization code grant
type, the client can specify a redirection URI via the "redirect_uri"
parameter.  If an attacker can manipulate the value of the
redirection URI, it can cause the authorization server to redirect
the resource owner user-agent to a URI under the control of the
attacker with the authorization code.

An attacker can create an account at a legitimate client and initiate
the authorization flow.  When the attacker's user-agent is sent to
the authorization server to grant access, the attacker grabs the
authorization URI provided by the legitimate client and replaces the
client's redirection URI with a URI under the control of the
attacker.  The attacker then tricks the victim into following the
manipulated link to authorize access to the legitimate client.

Once at the authorization server, the victim is prompted with a
normal, valid request on behalf of a legitimate and trusted client,
and authorizes the request.  The victim is then redirected to an
endpoint under the control of the attacker with the authorization
code.  The attacker completes the authorization flow by sending the
authorization code to the client using the original redirection URI
provided by the client.  The client exchanges the authorization code
with an access token and links it to the attacker's client account,
which can now gain access to the protected resources authorized by
the victim (via the client).

In order to prevent such an attack, the authorization server MUST
ensure that the redirection URI used to obtain the authorization code
is identical to the redirection URI provided when exchanging the
authorization code for an access token.  The authorization server
MUST require public clients and SHOULD require confidential clients
to register their redirection URIs.  If a redirection URI is provided
in the request, the authorization server MUST validate it against the
registered value.

Comment: Assuming allowed redirect_uris are preset and matched exactly during authorization code grant, is this no longer a concern? Also, thank you for the link!

Comment: Allowed redirect_uris are strong protection, but not everybody does it properly. Many people just use "*" because it is easier. Also, it is possible that hacker took control of one computer that is on the allowed list and trying to steal token requested from another one.